# mysterious associated behavior compiled with gfortran

Tags: fortran

I have the following short fortran code.

```
  !==============================================
  MODULE PREC
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: q=8
  END MODULE PREC

  !==============================================
  MODULE MOD_FIT
  USE prec         ! q

  TYPE spec
    INTEGER HL,HR
    COMPLEX(q), POINTER :: HMAT(:,:)   ! (HL,HR)
  END TYPE

  END MODULE MOD_FIT

  !==============================================
  PROGRAM MAIN
  USE prec
  USE MOD_FIT      ! spec
  IMPLICIT NONE
  !
  TYPE(spec) SMP

  write(*,*)'check associated:',associated(SMP%HMAT)

  END
```

I compiled it with the newest version gfortran, and ran it. The following is what I got

check associated: T

Should it be F as I hadn't initialize it at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the status of your pointer is *undefined*. You are not allowed to inquire it using `associated()` because it can result in anything.

What you should always do is to use *default initialization* of all pointer components and initialize them to `null()`.

```
TYPE spec
    COMPLEX(q), POINTER :: HMAT(:,:) => null()
END TYPE
```

After that you are guaranteed to get the expected result *false*.

Comment: Is this NULL() a special behavior for a pointer or can this be understood as assigning the pointer with an initial value?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It is a definition of an initial status of the pointer. `Null()` itself is an intrinsic function https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/NULL.html